# How to compress a JSON payload from Django Rest API

Tags: python, json, django

I have a particular Get response which has over 20mb of JSON payload, this takes a lot of time to load. I was wondering if there is a way to compress this payload a bit before sending it to the client.

**Note:** I'm new to the Django framework, kindly provide docs along with your answer so i can understand more.

Comment: use pagination if you can, 20mb will be too much even after compressing

Comment: No I can't use pagination here the requirement involves me to fetch entire data at once :(

Comment: Well then look at the question I linked